# Ranting against a poorly understood concept

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests

What verbs (or phrases) describe the behavior of expressing negative opinions on a topic the speaker is seriously misinformed about? What can be such a person called? "Droning"; "incompetent", "demagogue" or "ignorant" aren't quite the terms I'm looking for. Perhaps a combination of "judgmental" and "ignorant"?

Example:

> He was going on and on about how gays are depraved immoral animals who wanted to destroy the traditional marriage, but could not name a single marriage broken by, or crime committed in the name of homosexuality.

Comment: I'd go for **prejudiced**, although I am not sure it has quite the nuance of meaning that you want.

Comment: Please see  [this guidance from Stack Exchange Management](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity) about such questions.

Answer (score 4):

You example immediatley brings to mind [**bigot**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bigot), although that is not necessarily based on ignorance or misinformation:

> a person who is obstinately or intolerantly devoted to his or her own opinions and prejudices; especially : one who regards or treats the members of a group (such as a racial or ethnic group) with hatred and intolerance

One could argue, though, that such tenacity to one's preconceived ideas can only be the result of *willful* ignorance and the refusal to accept facts that contradict those preset opinions or refusing to become better informed.

Answer (score -1):

@oerkelens has given the perfect generalistic conviction that is required. since according to me a misinformation is not a disqualification for a speaker to not stick to his opinion firmly. no one can prove/confirm a incident since whatever information you receive will always be subject to modification In some cases also falsification for some personal gains. so expressing opinion with some prejudice based upon your natural instincts is isn't wrong. I'm talking generally, not regarding the example you have mentioned.